# Django's templatetag "cache" doesn't cache the queryset in template

Tags: django, caching, templatetags

I use cache tag like this :

```
{% cache 1200 special %}
<div id="recommended-topics" class="ui-ce ui-ce-simple">
   {{aticle_list}}   
</div>
{% endcache %}
```

I found that there is a key named `template.cache.special.d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e` in **memcache**.

however, I still find django execute the query to get the `article_list`

why this doesn't work??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First place I would check is the view which loads that template. Are you doing a query in the view to populate `article_list`?

If so, then your template cache may be working but you're still hitting the database to generate a queryset that's not being used.

If that's the case, the simplest solution would be to look at setting up [per-view caches](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#the-per-view-cache).